# Как писать один лог одновременно несколькими обработчиками? PHP

Tags: php, файлы, логирование

Вернее, обработчик один, но много запросов идут вместе (телеграмм бот). Заметил, что в логе в пиковые моменты далеко не вся информация записана, думаю из-за того, что за время пока скрипт откроет, закроет и зпишет файл - другой скрипт тоже открывает этот файл и записывает уже свои данные, прежние пропадают.
Как можно это пофиксить? Возможно ли создать какую-то очередь?

Comment: Воспользоваться одной из миллиона библиотек для логирования которые уже решили эту задачу